# Which completes first, a market order or stop order?

Tags: stocks, limit-order, market-order

Say the price of a stock is $3.00 a share.  At 10:00am Bob places a buy stop order for $3.02.  At 10:01am, Mary places a market order for the exact same number of shares.  Right after Mary places her order and before it can be filled, the price jumps to $3.07 and continues to climb.  Since it's above $3.02, Bob's order will be converted to a market order.  But, which order would get filled first (i.e. for the cheaper price on the climbing stock price)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mary's market order places a priority on execution, not price so  it is immediately routed to the exchange to be filled immediately.

Bob's stop order places a priority on price and it will be executed only if a  certain price is reached. When that price is reached, the  stop order becomes a market order.

If there are limited shares available at a lower price, Mary will have first dibs on them.  Bob will also be filled at that price unless share price rises before his order reaches the head of the queue.